# Changing triggers of existing scheduled task deployed via GPO

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012, group-policy

We have a scheduled task that is deployed via GPO. I want to change the triggers for this scheduled task.
I've updated the task in the GPO, but I can't get this change pushed to the clients. I've tried `gpupdate /force` and also rebooting the client machine.

If I manually remove the task from the client and then run `gpupdate /refresh` I get the new task with the new settings. I understand that I could always just create a new one, but I'd rather change the existing one.

As I'm testing this on the domain controller for now, both the client and the server in this scenario are windows server 2012 machines.

How do I **change** the existing scheduled task instead of recreating it with a new name?

Comment: Have you tried the option "Update" instead of "Create" when you make the task? [Like this](http://imgur.com/dsF5n43) The action "Update" should also create a task if it doesn't exist already, if it does exist it should just update it. :)

Comment: Good call! No I hadn't thought of that! And as you say, it worked beautifully. You should post that as an answer!

Comment: Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to change the task to Action: Update. [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HANch.png). This will update the task instead of creating a new one. "If the scheduled task does not exist, then the Update action creates a new scheduled task." 
You can read more about scheduled tasks here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725745(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Just for clarification, it also worked to just change the existing task's action to "Update" instead of create, no need to create a new one :)